# $L^p$ Convergence Implies Convergence in Measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Is the following true?

> Let $E \subseteq \Bbb{R}$ be some Lebesgue measurable set, and let $1 \le p <\infty$. Suppose $f_n,f \in L^p(E)$ and that $f_n \to f$ in norm. Then $f_n \to f$ in measure.

I know that it's true if $E$ is of finite measure. In this case, use the fact that $L^p(E) \subseteq L^{1}(E)$ and that $||f||_{1} \le c ||f||_p$ for every $f \in L^p(E)$. So, convergent sequences in $L^p(E)$ are also convergent sequences in $L^{1}(E)$. Then the conclusion follows from Chebyshev's inequality.

> But what if $m(E) = \infty$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\epsilon ^{p} m(\{x:|f_n(x)-f(x)| >\epsilon\}) \leq \int_{\{x:|f_n(x)-f(x)| >\epsilon\}} |f_n-f|^{p} dm \leq \int |f_n-f|^{p} dm \to 0. $

Comment: Is the middle inequality necessary?The version of Chebychev's inequality I'm using says that if $f$ is a nonnegative measurable function on $E$, then $m(\{x \in E \mid f(x) \ge \lambda \}) \le \frac{1}{\lambda} \int_{E} f$. So $$m(\{x:|f_n(x)-f(x)| \ge \epsilon\}) = m(\{x:|f_n(x)-f(x)|^p  \ge \epsilon^p \}) \le \frac{1}{\epsilon^p} \int_{E} |f_n - f|^p$$ or  is that not right?

Comment: You are right. But Chebychev's inequality is so trivial a result that I often include its proof instead of quoting it. The middle inequality actually gives proof of Chebychev's inequality.